# JWT as an API access control mechanism

Tags: jwt

how does JWT solve the problem of a web application serving the user with data from an API, while preventing the user from accessing the same API directly? Any encryption in the client side can be altered / intercepted.

Answer :
it doesn't, it's impossible to protect a public API without authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every request has a signature, changing the request will invalidate the signature

> Any encryption in the client side can be altered / intercepted.

this is not true because the client does not have the private key

Comment: the client holds the token. Without it, it can't access the API. This means, user can intercept the token and access the API himself

Comment: I probably misunderstood your question, could you please add some more details such as the architecture of your api? I think you can validate some of the claims in the token

Comment: my client side code shows the user data from an API. I don't want the user to be able to call the API directly